# display vector in decreasing order using another vector R

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors:

```
qing.emperors = c("Shunzhi","Kangxi","Yongzheng","Qianlong","Jiaqing")

reign.length = c(18,61,13,60,25)
```

I want to display the names of the emperors in order of decreasing reign length.

I'm  supposed to use the order function, and I'm having trouble using this to get to a vector with strings as a result. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try `qing.emperors[order(reign.length, decreasing = TRUE)]`

Comment: Thank you so much! That is perfect and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

another way with pipes:

```
library(dplyr)
data <-data.frame(qing.emperors, reign.length)
ordered <- data %>% arrange(desc(reign.length)) %>% select(qing.emperors, reign.length)
```